# c# datetimepicker addhours wont change

Tags: c#, time, datetimepicker

Alright so i want to add just want to set datetimepicker hours to specific time,

in windows forms i have datetimepicker1 and textbox1 here is my code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
        dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "HH:mm";

        dateTimePicker1.Value.AddHours(13);

        textBox1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.Hour.ToString();


    }
```

Now what ever i do it changes only when i set it from the form but it wont change hours when i set it to addhours(13). Any suggestions how i might fix this ?

Comment: `DateTime` is immutable, so `dateTimePicker1.Value.AddHours(13);
` would return a new `DateTime` object. You have to assign it back like `dateTimePicker1.Value =  dateTimePicker1.Value.AddHours(13);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AddHours` function does not change the value. You need to assign it's result back to the variable.

Use:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddHours(13);
```

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` is immutable.

You're creating a new `DateTime`, then throwing it away.